# Random letras sin repetir

Tags: random, pascal

Necesito ayuda para crear un programa que genere un random de letras (de la A a la U) y que no se repitan. Deben aparecer en un formato de de 3 columnas y 7 filas, aunque lo que más me interesa ahora mismo es el random, ya que al ejecutar el programa se repiten letras.

```
const
 MAX_TARJETAS_GRUPO= 7; //Tarjetas por grupo
 MAX_GRUPOS= 3; //Cantidad de grupos
 MAX_TARJETAS= MAX_TARJETAS_GRUPO*MAX_GRUPOS; //Total de tarjetas.
 MIN_TARJETA_VALOR= 'A'; //Tarjeta incial, en este caso letra A.
 MAX_TARJETA_VALOR= chr(MAX_TARJETAS+ord('A')-1); //Tarjeta final.
type
 tarjetas= MIN_TARJETA_VALOR..MAX_TARJETA_VALOR;
 grupo= array[1..MAX_TARJETAS_GRUPO] of tarjetas;
 mazo= array[1..MAX_TARJETAS] of tarjetas;

 var
 grupo1, grupo2, grupo3: grupo;
 deck: mazo;
 indice: char;
 it1, it2, it3, j,h, i, opcion: integer;
 letras: set of char;


begin


  randomize;
  writeln  ('Bienvenida');
  writeln;


  for it1:= 1 to 3 do begin
     writeln ('Secuencia ',it1,' de 3: ');
     for i:=1 to MAX_TARJETAS do begin
       deck[i]:= chr(random(ord(MAX_TARJETA_VALOR)-ord(MIN_TARJETA_VALOR)+1)+ord(MIN_TARJETA_VALOR));
       writeln (deck[i]);
     end;

  end;           


Gracias por vuestra ayuda.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar duplicados la única opción es consultar de alguna forma las letras (tarjetas) que ya has generado, para así evitar o saltar las repetidas.
A partir de esa idea hay varias formas de encararlo.

La primera ocurrencia es consultar en cada paso del "bucle for interior" las tarjetas ya generadas, para saber si la actual que estás generando ya existe. En este caso hay que cambiar el `FOR` por un `WHILE`.
Lo malo es que ese bucle `WHILE` no es óptimo, porque a medida que se van dando repeticiones es más difícil encontrar la letras que faltan. Eso genera lo que llamamos "colisiones" y es posible que en lugar de ejecutar la sentencia interior 21 veces (como hace tu programa ahora) llegues a ejecutarla del orden de 230 veces.

La segunda ocurrencia es generar una lista con todas las letras/tarjetas (en un `array`) y a medida que vas ejecutando el `Random` y encontrando una, la eliminas de la lista. Y la siguiente pasada, sólo ejecutas el `Random` sobre las letras/tarjetas que te quedan. De esta forma en las mismas 21 pasadas del `FOR` conseguirás todas las letras/tarjetas sin repetición.

Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado por fin!!

Answer (score 0):

Una técnica común para obtener una lista aleatoria de elementos sin repetir, es mantener una lista de los elementos que no han sido seleccionados y, en cada iteración, ir seleccionando y eliminando un elemento de esta lista.

En pascal moderno, podemos valernos de la clase TList genérica para conseguirlo, por ejemplo:

```
program AleatorioSinRepetir;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Generics.Collections;

var
  Pendientes: TList<Char>;
  Ch: Char;
  Indice: Integer;
  Fila, Columna: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  Pendientes := TList<Char>.Create;
  try
    for Ch := 'A' to 'U' do
      Pendientes.Add(Ch);

    while Pendientes.Count > 0 do
    begin
      Indice := Random(Pendientes.Count);
      Ch := Pendientes[Indice];
      Pendientes.Delete(Indice);
      Write(Ch, ' ');
    end;
  finally
    Pendientes.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Nos devuelve algo como:

```
Q J S I G K R H M B C O N L T P E A F D U
```

Si no tienes acceso a un compilador moderno de pascal, puedes lograr lo mismo con un arreglo estático, haciendo el *borrado* a mano, mediante un corrimiento de los elementos del arreglo y llevando una variable con la cantidad de elementos válidos en él, yo le he llamado a esta variable `contadorPendientes`:

```
program AleatorioSinRepetirVintage;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

const
  MaxElementos = 3 * 7;
var
  Pendientes: array[1..MaxElementos] of char;
  Ch: Char;
  Indice: Integer;
  Fila, Columna: Integer;
  ContadorPendientes: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  Indice := 0;
  for Ch := 'A' to 'U' do
  begin
    Inc(Indice);
    Pendientes[Indice] := Ch;
  end;
  ContadorPendientes := Indice;

  while ContadorPendientes > 0 do
  begin
    Indice := Random(ContadorPendientes) + 1;
    Ch := Pendientes[Indice];
    for I := Indice to ContadorPendientes - 1 do
      Pendientes[I] := Pendientes[I + 1];
    dec(ContadorPendientes);
    Write(Ch, ' ');
  end;
end.
```

Este me ha dado este resultado en la corrida de prueba:

```
M D N K L F B A O I G H E T U P Q J S R C
```

No he agregado comentarios al código, pues considero que se auto-explica. Si algo te genera duda o no puedes adaptarlo a tu proyecto no dudes en dejar un comentario.

Comment: Más o menos era lo que yo quería explicarle, aunque no le pese código "por no completarle los deberes" (que creo que por ahí va la cosa)  ;-D
Quería que lo intentara él o que le preguntara a ChatGPT...

Comment: Germán, comprendo tu punto. En lo general, intento responder con código a estas preguntas. El que no quiere aprender, encontrará la forma de pasar por aquí sin hacerlo. Yo he aprendido mucho leyendo código, antes de poder escribirlo. Fué una suerte para mi tener acceso al código fuente de la RTL de pascal, así como al de TurboVision en su momento, por ejemplo. No dejo de aprender de esa manera.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @alphabetico  Por favor, puntúa y marca las respuestas que te han sido útiles, así otrosw usuarios que posteriormente visiten las preguntas tienen más información acerca de las respuestas que más te han ayudado. Gracias.